# Integrating Spice within larger system model

Tags: ltspice, spice, pspice, ngspice

Is there a way to integrate spice within a broader system model that allows for programming?

In particular I am interested in simulating a digital feedback controller whos next output depends upon the current system status.

Ideally at each time step I would like spice to take as input a set of voltages/current and as output a set of voltages/current.

Comment: One of the simplest things I could think of is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fscTD.png). However, if your aim is modelling, it might help to think of the model not n terms of an exploded view of an FPGA (for example), but in terms of what it does, its *behaviour*. That will help with simulation time. It's one thing to create a gate-level equivalent of an integrator, and something else to use a simple G+T+R that will achieve the same thing in a fraction of the time. But, given your vague question, that's about all I can say: is it the same SPICE, two different ones, what "system model", ...?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, suppose I am interested torque control of a motor. I can simulate the motor as a series of resistor, inductor and voltage source. I can vary the voltage source to simulate changes in load which will impact the speed.  Conversely I can take the current current and and feed it into a program to produce the torque, which will induce a change in speed to update the voltage. Point is I want to be able to pragmatically update spice parameters at each time step.

Comment: If you want an actual code, then you're better off looking into Simulink, or SciLab, or the likes. But if what you're interested in is the *behaviour* of that control block, it's very possible in just about any SPICE. It sounds like what you want is to build some controller for a motor (FoC?), and that has been done very successfully. It might help to search for what you actually want as keywords, not something as vague as "is it possible to build something".

Comment: It's not possible to simulate these systems with a standard ODE solver or Simulink. Simscape maybe but I am not sure.  Control response is state dependent, at its core I need to be able to read and write voltages at each time step using some programming language.

Comment: Are you sure you're not overthinking this? Do you really need to write states *at every step*? Are you writing them manually, or are they automatically determined via the control loop? Can you draw, in Paint or whatever else, a block schematic showing exactly what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Beginning to sound like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

**COSIMULATION** is the term you are looking for.

Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceHoUoHl9q4) that is about a DC motor cosimulation with Pspice.

When you have more time, take a look at a detailed presentation on [SLPS](https://www.ema-eda.com/sites/ema/files/resources/files/CDNLive%202016_PSPice_MATLAB%20paper%20%281%29.pdf)